# Shell script: if multiple conditions

Tags: shell-script, shell, scripting

I want to create a shell script that echos something if 3 directories don't exist.

Here is the code I wrote:
test.sh:

```
if [ ! -d "/home/unix/POSTagger2" ] || [! -d "/home/unix/POSTagger2/stanford-parser-full-2015-12-09"] || [! -d "/home/unix/POSTagger2/stanford-corenlp-full-2015-12-09"]; then
echo "Nope"
fi
```

When I run it, I get this error:

```
./test.sh: line 1: [!: command not found
```

What's wrong with my syntax?

Comment: In the first condition, you had it right. Doing the same in the second condition would be the first thing which I would have done…

Comment: `[` is not a token, it is a command (another name for the command `test`) as such it must be separated by space(s). Similar case is `]` which is a command parameter so it must be separated by a space too.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are missing some spaces, for example `[!` must be `[ !` and `"]` must be `" ]` look to the corrected code:

```
#!/bin/bash
if 
[ ! -d "/home/unix/POSTagger2" ] || 
[ ! -d "/home/unix/POSTagger2/stanford-parser-full-2015-12-09" ] || 
[ ! -d "/home/unix/POSTagger2/stanford-corenlp-full-2015-12-09" ] 
then
      echo "Nope"
fi
```

Another way for your code:

```
#!/bin/bash
for dir in "/home/unix/POSTagger2" "/home/unix/POSTagger2/stanford-parser-full-2015-12-09" "/home/unix/POSTagger2/stanford-corenlp-full-2015-12-09"; do
     if [ ! -d "$dir" ]; then echo nope ; break; fi 
done
```

Comment: bash is not the only shell in unix. There is pure shell /bin/sh

Answer (score 9):

You need a space between the `[` and the `!` for things to work correctly. This is because `[` is implemented as shell-builtin command (it even used to be a separate exectuable `/usr/bin/[`).

You can also use:

```
if [ ! -d "/home/unix/POSTagger2" -o ! -d "/home/unix/POSTagger2/stanford-parser-full-2015-12-09" -o ! -d "/home/unix/POSTagger2/stanford-corenlp-full-2015-12-09") ] ; then
    echo "Nope"
fi
```

Bash offers an alternative `[[` that is implemented as en expression. `[[` uses `&&`, `||`, etc. instead of `-a`, `-o` as operators.

```
if [[ ! (-d "/home/unix/POSTagger2" && -d "/home/unix/POSTagger2/stanford-parser-full-2015-12-09" && -d "/home/unix/POSTagger2/stanford-corenlp-full-2015-12-09") ]] ; then
    echo yes
fi
```

Edit: Thanks to comments from @LucianoAndressMartini and @pabouk for important corrections to my understanding.

Comment: No! You're wrong. Try moving out the /usr/bin/[ to other folder, and you see that the conditional statement still works fine because its a bash built-in, this executable you see is not being used by bash, it is offered as a compatibility option for some ancient shell, so they can run some bash code without errors.

Comment: It's a builtin command in bash, but the fact that it acts like any command and needs a space still applies.

Comment: Yes this part of the answer still applies. It is a great answer, the only wrong thing is about thinking that "[" is not a shell built-in.

Comment: Well I learned something new! I never revised my view of `[` since 1999, apparently.

Comment: Thank you friend! I will give +1 for you. I'm wrong since 1999 too, i learned it a few months ago here in stack exchange.

Comment: `[[` is not a command. It is a token and some special characters have a different meaning between `[[` and `]]`. Also it is not POSIX-compliant and works only in some shells like bash or korn. See for example http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031

Comment: @LucianoAndressMartini `[` is not a shell built-in in `sh`.  All the world's not Linux.

Comment: Yes, but it is a shell built-in for bash and zsh (and every unix running bash or zsh). However the executable still exists on path for compatibilities if you decide to use other shells like a more legacy sh. If you want you can issue this command : "builtin [", if the return is something like bash: [: missing `]', you are running with the builtin version even if you have "[ " as executable in path, and unix shells may vary a lot... some other Unix-like runs bash today... or shells with test command as builtin.